# RTK Query Error returning my own html and not the API response

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my project I'm using Redux Toolkit Query to fetch data from an API. And when I use it on my component it gives me PARSIN_ERROR, because it is returning me my own html base template and not the API response...

This is my **service** code.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
  'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.CRYPTO_API_KEY,
  'X-RapidAPI-Host': process.env.CRYPTO_API_HOST,
};

const createRequest = (url) => ({
  url,
  headers: cryptoApiHeaders,
});

export const CryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'CryptoApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.CRYPTO_API_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCryptos: builder.query({
      query: (count) => createRequest(`/coins?limit=${count}`),
    }),
    getCryptoById: builder.query({
      query: (coin_uuid) => createRequest(`/coin/${coin_uuid}`),
    })
  })
});

export const {
  useGetCryptosQuery,
  useGetCryptoByIdQuery
} = CryptoApi
```

This is my Store code.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

import { CryptoApi } from "../Services/CryptoApi"

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [CryptoApi.reducerPath]: CryptoApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(CryptoApi.middleware),
})
```

Here I inject the Provider.

```
import { store } from './app/store'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Here is where i call it in the component

```
import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../Services/CryptoApi';

const Home = () => {

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetCryptosQuery(10);

  return (
    <>
      {
        error ? (
            console.error(error.error)
          )
        :
        isLoading ? (
          console.log(isLoading)
        )
        :
        data ? (
          console.log('Passed: ', data)
        ) : null
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

And this is the response
[image]

As you can see, it is returning my own html template in the error... I'm working on this all day and yet don't know how to solve it...

OBS: all the env properties are correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same parsing error in my React app using Redux Toolkit Query. I created my app with Vite and had to add server options to the vite.config.js file. You can read more about server options in their documentation here: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.
In my case, I was working with localhost and using a proxy for my backend. So to get the API request to work, my code for the vite.config.js looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. Finally, I fixed it. The issue was with the API base URL. In this line '`baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.CRYPTO_API_URL })`'. Here 'process.env' wasn't working as expected, resulting in the wrong API being used, which caused the error.

First, solve the issue with 'process.env' or use the direct base URL (if security is not a concern).